# How can I create a new url from user input in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What I need is to redirect a User to a new "home page" with data taken from form input that the user would have entered before clicking the `submit` button.

For example (but not what is exactly required): if a form asks the user Bob to enter data about himself, when Bob submits the form he will be taken to a new formatted page `example.com/bob` with all the information he entered.

A new jsp page would not be created, but somehow I need the controller to take the url and search the database for the user "Bob" and format the directed page with all Bob's information.

Comment: Do you need to generate a new url or also a new **page**?

Comment: Not a new page, I just need to direct a user to a new "prettier" url, and have the controller take the value of that url to query the database for an object with the same key identifier

Comment: When i say "prettier" i mean that i know i can put it in as a GET value, like "example.com/?name=bob", but i would much rather it be simple as "example.com/bob"

Comment: what I mean is: do you have a template for this user-details-page, or do you have to generate it dinamically? what do you mean with: *"A new jsp page would not be created"*?

Comment: I have a template for the page that will be created, for example user-home.jsp, and my controller should take the value in the url and query the database, and then return the jsp with a model of the object so the jsp can put all the attributes in the format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a url like `example.com/bob` using *path variables*.

In your controller you need something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/{name}")
public String userDetails(@PathVariable String name){
    // retrieve user details from DB by username
    return "redirect:/" + name;
}
```

Take a look at Spring MVC [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates).

Answer (score 1):

```
User userFind = userMetier.getUserByEmail(user.getEmail);
Return "home2.html?name="+userFind.getName()+"?email="+userFind.getEmail() ;
```